# How do I emulate 256-bit integer math ops on a system with only a 32-bit int?

Tags: c++, c++11, int64

I'd like to write a deadsimple bignum class using a series of (unsigned) integers. I can loosely see how addition and subtraction would work, but division and multiplication is another story. I know 32-bit compilers can emuate 64-bit int's by splitting the int64 in two int32's. I'm looking for an efficient method to do that.

I'd like to have C++ code, not assembly. Speed is no primary concern, but the most efficient solution without assemble is always nice to have.

Comment: Loosely speaking: start with long multiplication and long division (which you learned when you were 6 or whatever) in base 2^16. This at least works, then optimize to taste (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Fast_multiplication_algorithms_for_large_inputs).

Comment: All C++ compilers support `long long`, which is at least 64bits.

Comment: This is a requirement, rather than a question. What is your specific problem? Are you looking for example code?

Comment: @DeadMG: There are a lot of C++ compilers out there, not all are particularly compliant, and `long long` isn't required until C++11. There is probably an 8-bit C++ compiler out there that doesn't bother with 64 bits. Still, I'd be interested to hear from @rubenvb what he's using…

Comment: I updated the question to more clearly state what I tried to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps [this](https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/verse/trunk/verse/v_bignum.c) can serve as a starting point. It implements up to 2,048-bit unsigned integers, using a base-65,536 representation. This means each digit fits in 16 bits, and we can trivially detect overflow (even when multiplying) by simply using 32 bits for the results.

This is C code however, but should be trivial to port to C++, or just use as an inspiration. It's very much optimized for readability rather than speed since this is not exactly the kind of stuff I'm good at. :)

Answer (score 1):

You'd best have a look at [arbitrary precision arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) which will explain the thinking behind the process of emulating higher precision processors than then one that your code is running on.

Answer (score 1):

Purchase a hardback book called NUMERICAL RECIPES IN C++ and you will find what you are looking for on pages starting on 20.6 page p916 onto to p925

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with just using `long long`?  That's guaranteed to be at
least 64 bits.  Otherwise, your Knuth (vol. 2) should provide the basic
algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple byte array. You can have size of integer whatever you want*. You just have to operate in binary and take endianess into consideration (your bits will be 7-6-5-4-3-2-1-0-15-14-13...)

*RAM is limited

Answer (score 0):

for arbitrary sizes, give [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) a spin, it should also work for your 64bit math on 32bit if for some reason you can't rely on the compiler to do it for you.

Comment: GMP is a poor performance choice for small Integers (it typically works better on Integers larger than 256 bits).

Comment: @user2284570 What about the mpn low-level interface? Does it perform well for integers of 192..256 bit? That API seems not to use heap so it should perform well using non-heap data, doesn't it?

Comment: @Silicomancer time spent in algorithm selection ?

Comment: @Silicomancer `mpn_mul_2` is also undocumented.